# accessing specific intervals in list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list containing the system time from a machine. Since the list contains only the milliseconds part, the values don´t go beyond 1000.
For better viewing I want to add i*1000 to certain intervals in this list for each time the list skips 1000. For better understanding i will give my input list and what my output list should look like:

```
inputlist = [300,600,900,200,500,800,100,400]
```

etc, the output list should look like this:

```
outputlist = [300,600,900,1200,1500,1800,2100,2400]
```

since I want the list to start with zero i subtracted the first element of the list from each element giving me a new inputlist:

```
inputlist_new = [0,300,600,-100,200,500,-200,100]
```

which should give me a new outputlist like:

```
outputlist_new = [0,300,600,900,1200,1500,1800,2100]
```

I tried creating a list containing the indices of each element < 0 to cut the list into intervals, to multiply the thousands on each interval but I am not able to do so. My code for this index list is this:

```
list_index = [i for i, j in enumerate(inputlist_new) if j < 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution myself: i copied the list i want to change into a new one, just for the sake of maybe using it later (so this is not necessary for the solution) and then used 2 for loops:

```
inputlist_new = [0,300,600,-100,200,500,-200,100]
inputlist2 = inputlist_new.copy()
for x in range(len(list_index)):
    for y in range(list_index[x],len(inputlist2)):
        inputlist2[y] = inputliste2[y]+1000
```

this gave me the wanted output

Comment: Just for curiosity:
does anyone know how to convert the 2 for loops into a list comprehension?